# Is it possible to have a form submit a comma separated list via GET?

Tags: jquery, forms

Let's say I have a form that contains a whole bunch of check boxes with the same name, c. Each checkbox has an integer value assigned to it.

When the form is submitted, via GET, I'd like the url to look like `www.url.com/?c=1,2,3,4,5`

and not

`www.url.com/?c=1&c=2&c=3&c=4&c=5`

Possible? or will I have to capture the form submit via jQuery, loop through each checked box, and tack on my own url var?

Comment: I think you will need to use jQuery for this, like you mentioned.

Comment: Consider using `|` or something instead. That should make this easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to resort to Javascript to accomplish this.

In jQuery, this is how you might go about it:

```
$('form').submit(function()
{
    var values = [];

    $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"][name="c"]:checked').each(function()
    {
        values.push(this.value);
    });

    window.location = 'www.url.com/?c=' + values.join(',');
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for going the extra mile and providing the code too!

Comment: Hi, I came across your answer here but can't get it to work. Obviously I'm doing something wrong. Can you add html to go with this code or a jsfiddle example please?

Comment: @mr.data1 - Post a fiddle with your code that doesn't work and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/95feeh8n/

When I submit I get the following `index.php?action=searchresults&listing_id=1&listing_id=2` but I want `index.php?action=searchresults&listing_id=1,2`  What am I missing for this to work?

Comment: @mr.data1 - What you have there should work. Try returning false.

Answer (score 0):

```
function form_to_submit() {

        var form_to_submit = $('#form');

        var queryArray = form_to_submit.serializeArray();

        const queryArrayReduced = queryArray.reduce((acc, {name, value}) => 
        {

            if(name in acc) {
            acc[name] = acc[name].concat(','+value);
            } else {
            acc[name] ??= value;
            }

            return acc;
        }, {});

        var queryString = decodeURIComponent($.param(queryArrayReduced));

        window.location.href = '?' + queryString;

}
```